# Heroku Cannot Get / react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm, yarnpkg

I am using React & NodeJS and yarn package manager. my app works fine locally. but when I upload it to Heroku it says Cannot Get /

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

My webpack.config.prod.js file looks like this

```
 const JS_BUNDLE   = 'bundle.js';

module.exports = function (paths, loaders, plugins) {
  return {
    output: {
      path: paths.dist,
      filename: JS_BUNDLE,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        loaders.style,
      ],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
      plugins.loaderOptions({
        minimize: true,
      }),
      plugins.uglifyJs({
        output: {
          comments: false,
        },
        compress: {
          warnings: false,
          drop_console: true,
          dead_code: true,
          unused: true,
          conditionals: true,
                comparisons: true,
                sequences: true,
                evaluate: true,
                if_return: true,
                join_vars: true,
        },
      }),
      plugins.definePlugin,
      plugins.genHtml({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'template.html',
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

Which I believe it does not create index.html when it runs yarn and my scripts on package.json

```
"scripts": {
"watch-dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot --inline",
"api": "PORT=3000 nodemon server.js",
"start": "node server.js"
```

}

Heroku Logs

> 2017-11-09T09:31:46.907824+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
>
> 2017-11-09T09:31:48.165220+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 139 - 55.164 ms
>
> 2017-11-09T09:31:48.154963+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=hksmetal.herokuapp.com request_id=0692c07a-6f96-4708-8a74-30704fbad48e fwd="213.247.123.26" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=128ms status=404 bytes=543 protocol=https

Thanks in advance if any suggestions

Comment: Please post the logs  from the heroku terminal for the app ..

Comment: yes! my mistake I have added

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a return to index.html. `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));`

`app.get('*', function(req, res) {     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/index.html')); });`